# How to query "strict" parameter?

Tags: javascript, express, sequelize.js

So I have the following piece of code:

```
exports.findAll = (req, res) => {
    const title = req.query.title;
    var condition = title ? { title: { [Op.like]: `%${title}%` } } : null;
  
    File.findAll({ where: condition })
      .then(data => {
        res.send(data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({
          message:
            err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving files."
        });
      });
};
```

If I GET `http://serverip/api/gta/sa/?title=m4` it returns me another file in the database that includes 'm4' in its title first and then the actual object with the title m4. Is there a way to force the GET to return to me the file with the exact title instead? I do not need to be served other files that may include 'm4' in its title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
title: { [Op.like]: `%${title}%` }
```

use:

```
title: { [Op.eq]: title }
```